# IOS safari 13.1 permission for DeviceMotionEvent

Tags: javascript, ios, safari, devicemotion

DeviceMotionEvent.requestPermission work well for the first use. 
If user cancel access for motion sensors in first time dialog window will not appear for future calls of requestPermission function. And promise is always fulfilled with response === 'denied'.

How to prompt user again?

Answer (score 1):

I have encountered the same issue today.

Restart Safari will give user a second chance.